# Text in drop down should be green not red

Tags: html, css, date-comparison

I have a drop down menu which displays an exam's name, date and time and what I want to do is that if an exam date has been passed from the current date or time, then the text is displayed in red, else text is green.

Problem I am having is that if the current date is 10-11-2012 (which is today) and if an exam has this date and time below:

10-11-2012, 16:00:00

It displays the text in red and not in green. The problem is that it is not recognising the current time, it thinks that as it is the current date, it should be red, but because the current time hasn't passed in the current date, then it should be green.

The database stores the date as 2012-11-10 and the time in the database stored as 16:00:00. While in the drop down as mentioned it is stored as: 10-11-2012, 16:00:00

Below is the code:

```
<style>
.red{ color:red; }
.green{ color:green; }
</style>
```

...

```
    $now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
       if(strtotime($now) > strtotime($dbSessionDate)){
             $class = 'red';
        } else {
             $class = 'green';
        }
        $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s' class='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $class, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), $dbSessionTime) . PHP_EOL;
        }
```

$now should be the current date and time and $dbSessionDate should be 10-11-2012

**UPDATE:**

```
$sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo strtotime($now).'<br>';
echo strtotime('10-11-2012, 16:00:00');
while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
   if(strtotime($now) > strtotime($dbSessionDate)){
         $class = 'red';
    } else {
         $class = 'green';
    }
    $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s' class='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $class, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;
    }


$sessionHTML .= '</select>';

$assessmentform = "<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post'>
<p><strong>Assessments:</strong> {$sessionHTML} </p>   
</form>";
```

Comment: 'Should probably remove jquery and javascript tags, and add the php tag.

Comment: @CMB: Could you show what are the values of `strtotime($now)` and `strtotime($dbSessionDate)` are? Because obviously, one of them is not exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the CSS classes `.red` and `.green` do actually have the correct `color` property as red and green? (make sure you didn't switch the colors by mistake)

Comment: @Aziz well $now should be the current date and time and $dbSessionDate should be `10-11-2012, 16:00:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to be OK. Try:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
echo strtotime($now).'<br>';
echo strtotime('10-11-2012, 16:00:00');
```

and check the server time.

**UPDATE:**

Replace:

```
$sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s' class='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $class, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;
```

with:

```
$sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s' style='color: %s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $class, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;
```

to prevent css mistake.

Or replace:

```
strtotime($now) > strtotime($dbSessionDate)
```

with:

```
strtotime($now) < strtotime($dbSessionDate)
```

Comment: Both echos display this `1352528283
1352563200`. What does this mean and I want to know if I can change the time display in the drop dowm menu from 16:00:00 to 16:00 for example?

Comment: It means [number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Result is ok and in $class will be stored 'green'. The root of the problem will be elsewhere. Try check $sessionHTML...

Comment: And you can remove last two zeros.

Comment: What is best way to check $sessionHTML as it is already echoed? Do I need to do strtotime on $deSessionTime as well? I changed the time format for hour from `h` to `H` to make it 24 hours with leading zeros. I have removed the zeros, just text color not changing still to green when current date met but current time not passed

Comment: strtotime($now) > strtotime($dbSessionDate) is correct and sprintf too. The option color must be green. Maybe is $sessionHTML redefined somewhere.

Comment: I have updated code so you can see what the code looks like, the only other time it is defined is in a from which you can see in the updated code

Comment: Do you really want a green color? 10-11-2012, 16:00:00 is now past.

Comment: I have changed the time to 23:00:00 so I will see if it works for 23:00:00. If the date/time has passed the current date/time, then it should be red, if not then it should be green. So changing it to `strtotime($now) < strtotime($dbSessionDate)` wont work as that those sessions with their dates and times which is now passed will be green when I want them red

Comment: instead of `strtotime($now)` if I changed it to `time()` then it actually worked. Thanks